# Check if item exists in array before pushing to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    let ranVert1 = floor(random(1, vertices.length - 1)) + 1;
    let ranVert2 = floor(random(1, vertices.length - 1)) + 1;

    let found = lines.filter((line, index, array) => {
        console.log(`Line ${index}:`);
        console.log(line.v1);
    });
    if(found.length > 0){
        continue;
    }
    lines.push(new Line(ranVert1, ranVert2));
}
```

It loops through each vertex in a vertices array, and creates a line between any 2 vertices. But I want to remove duplicates.

So if we have vertices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Then it generates line [2, 4]. I don't want it to generate another line that is either [2, 4] or [4, 2].

What's the best way to do this? (Preferably without using a for loop)

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

A vertex looks like this:

```
{
   x: 300,
   y: 500
}
```

A line looks like this:

```
{
   v1: 5,
   v2: 6
}
```

Comment: Put this as an answer so i can accept it please @trincot

Comment: Alright. Posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a matrix of zeroes, where rows and columns correspond to the indices of the first and second vertex. Put a 1 in that matrix when you have output the pair. If there is already a 1, don't output it.

I assume you also want to avoid pairs like [2, 2] -- creating a line to the same vertex.

So something like this:

```
let matrix = vertices.map(() => Array(vertices.length).fill(0));

for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    let ranVert1 = floor(random(1, vertices.length - 1)) + 1;
    let ranVert2 = floor(random(1, vertices.length - 1)) + 1;

    let found = matrix[ranVert1][ranVert2] || ranVert1 == ranVert2;
    if (found) {
        continue;
    }
    matrix[ranVert1][ranVert2] = 1;
    matrix[ranVert2][ranVert1] = 1; // To avoid the other direction as well
    lines.push(new Line(ranVert1, ranVert2));
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an array with all possible pairs, [shuffle that array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array), and then take a slice from that array.

Something like this:

```
let lines = vertices.flatMap((v1, i) => 
    vertices.slice(i+1).map(v2 => new Line(v1, v2))
);
shuffle(lines); // see link for implementation of shuffle
lines.splice(vertices.length); // keep only first few elements
```

Note: In your code you generate `vertices.length` lines, but you also write *"...creates a line between any 2 vertices"*. It does not create a line between **any** 2 vertices, since there are more such lines possible than `vertices.length`: actually there are `vertices.length*(vertices.length-1)/2` such lines possible. If you really want all of those, then definitely go for the second solution, as the first one may need some time to *randomly* generate the only one left when it reaches the end of the generation process. The `shuffle` algorithm does not have this problem, and you can then leave out the `splice`.